# Getting external PS1 value inside bash script

Tags: bash, environment-variables

I need to get the value of the `PS1` variable inside a bash script.

I know that running the script with a dot before makes bash pass env variables to the script, but I need to get `PS1` regardless of how it is invoked, since I don't trust who will run the script.

How do I get it?

**Update**:
the variable has been exported in `/etc/profile`, but I cannot get it:

```
[ Test ] root@myhost:~# export | grep PS1
declare -x PS1="[ Test ] \\u@\\h:\\w\\\$ "
[ Test ] root@myhost:~# cat test.sh 
echo $PS1
[ Test ] root@myhost:~# bash test.sh
```

I get no output from the last command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This variable is somehow treated in a special way in bash (but eg in AIX or HPUX `sh` that i know you can access it even while non-interactive). It's being used only in interactive shell, so there's no possibility to get access to its value in non-interactive invocation.

Sorry, it's no answer, but that's how it is...

Comment: Hi, can you provide a reference for your answer?

Comment: Found what I was searching for in man bash, section INVOCATION. You are right. Thanks!

Comment: @Andrea Spadaccini: Sorry, i've got some real life with no net access last weekend:) But you seem to have found your information, right?

Answer (score 8):

Start your test script with 'bash -i'; this makes it behave like a login shell and (amongst other things) sets PS1.

If your script will be run as an executable (.e.g ./test.sh) then you can also provide -i on the initial line, like this:

```
#!/bin/bash -i
```

**Update:** This only works if your script is executed directly, e.g.

```
$ ./test.sh
```

and **not** as:

```
$ bash test.sh
```

as that runs it in a non-interactive shell again. If you want to use bash from the command line, then do it like this:

```
$ bash -i test.sh
```

Comment: Thanks, but it does not work. I created a test script with the suggested shebang header and a simple `echo Prompt: $PS1`, but I get the output `Prompt: `.

Comment: I get the $PS1 output from this.

Comment: Andrea: were you running the script with `bash test.sh`? See the update.

Comment: Note that this is not actually getting the "current" value for `PS1`, it is running the .bashrc file to generate a new value. This may be effectively what you want, but there is a distinction.

Answer (score 2):

5 years later....because i used the following solution after finding this question.

If you want you can use the -i flag in the header and it seems to keep the environment during the script without having to run it in a special manner. I.e.

```
#!/bin/bash -i
echo "$PS1"
```

I don't know if this has any other weird behaviors, but it worked for what I needed.

Comment: And 3 years later again, Note that this is not actually getting the "current" value for `PS1`, it is running the .bashrc file to generate a new value. This may be effectively what you want, but there is a distinction